# How can I modify animation from FBX with only hierarchy?

Tags: animation, rigging, .fbx

I imported animation from FBX. It only consist of a hierarchy with points. No rigs, bones or mesh. But the animation works fine. Can this animation be edited? I can't even change Object Mode and attach mesh or rig.[image: import FBX animation to blender]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new rig, with one bone for every empty of your animation. Then select a point, shift select the armature, go to pose mode, select the correspondent bone and press Ctrl Shift C > copy transform.

Repeat for every point/bone.

When finished go to Pose mode > Animation > Bake action, turn on "Visual Keying" and "Clear constraints" and bake.

You will have the action exactly transferred to the rig.

Comment: Thank a lot! This works perfectly!